# Is there anyway to attach a non-Steam game's screenshots to Steam?

Tags: steam, world-of-warcraft

I use Steam to run World of Warcraft, but WoW is not a Steam game. Since I [can't bind PrintScreen as the screenshot key in Steam](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1807945), I can't take a Steam screenshot at the same time as I take an in-game screenshot. Also, I have an addon in WoW that automatically takes screenshots given certain conditions. Having the screenshots allows me to use Steams browser to navigate screenshots, as well as use them as a background on the game's Libary page.

Is there a way to simply attach World of Warcraft's screenshots directory to Steam's?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The steam forums have a few answers:

1. [Renaming a steam-screenshot](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2532102)
2. [Workaround via VLC](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1974965)

Both should work just fine but do take some effort ;)

The first option is to make a screenshot ingame, give the name of that screenshot to the screenshot you want to add and to copy the renamed screenshot over the steam-screenshot.

The second option requires some more steps:

- [Download](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/), install and add VLC to your steam library.
- Run VLC from Steam.
- Select open file and select your image (select `any file` is necessary).
- Go into full screen modus (double-click the screen).
- Make a screenshot with Steam.

Comment: Can you summarize in your answer? We generally don't post links by themselves as answers.

Comment: @Fluttershy I'll edit right now :)